# How to change the Eclipse Debug view font?

Tags: eclipse

What font preferenc drives the Eclipse Debug view font? I feel I have tried all the ones that make sense (including the ones under Debug) and none seem to change it.

I'm on  Eclipse 4.2.1 on OSX 10.8.2 if it matters.

Comment: tell what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Eclipse to change the font used for Package Explorer, Debug View and other such views. You can only change the font for editor views. This is a policy decision on the part of the Eclipse developers. The font used is the one set by the general look-and-feel for whatever desktop you are using.

On Windows 7, you can affect many of the eclipse GUI fonts, including the Debug View and the Project Explorer by going to:

Control Panel -> Personalization -> Window Color and Appearance -> Advanced Appearance Settings

Change the font size for "Message Box".

Of course this messes with the appearance of other stuff in your OS, but I've found that tolerable compared to squinting at the debug view...

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse for Mac m1: go to preferences ->general->appreances -> colors and fonts ->select any option under Debug and click edit.

[image: preferences]

[image: Edit fonts]